# How can i export my models without any offset

Tags: export

I have a 3D model and I am trying to export each part of the model that makes it to an OBJ and JSON format, but I notice I get an offset as the models are not centered at their own origin after exporting. How do I export each of the at their own individually centered origin.

Comment: Could you add a blender and export program screenshot?

Comment: @batFINGER do you mean the screenshot of my export page ?

Answer (score 1):

Try centering the object in the center of the world before export using <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> and if your model moves into a weird position, move the model to the center manually and use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to apply the location and export afterwards.

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt work

Comment: I edited the question, i figured out the previous wasn't detailed enough